# Which is correct - PayPal documentation or their PHP IPN code samples?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

According to PayPal's [Implementing an IPN Listener](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/#specs) documentation, the correct sequence of events for an IPN listener is:

- listener receives a notification
- **listener sends an empty HTTP 200 response**
- listener prepends `cmd=_notify-validate` onto the notification it received and sends it back to PayPal via POST
- PayPal responds with either `VERIFIED` or `INVALID`
- listener handles the notification appropriately

However, the sample code (apparently supplied by PayPal) on [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php) does things in a different order:

- listener receives a notification
- listener prepends `cmd=_notify-validate` onto the notification it received and sends it back to PayPal via POST
- PayPal responds with either `VERIFIED` or `INVALID`
- listener handles the notification appropriately
- **listener sends an empty HTTP 200 response**

Does the sample code work correctly?  If not, why is PayPal citing this code as an example?  If so, why does PayPal's documentation *not* reflect the correct coding sequence?  ...or does the order not matter?

Comment: Did you ask this question direct to paypal ?

Comment: PayPal isn't open at 2:30AM EST, and trying to find somewhere on PayPal's site to ask a technical question such as this is "nearly" impossible - I *may* have stumbled across the link to do so ten years ago, but their site has *radically* changed since then, and their documentation has failed to keep up - which is why I'm asking the *community* if they have any experience or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the answer is "It doesn't matter which order it's done in" - as long as the response is received within the timeout window.

I found this information buried on the PayPal site as one of the possible answers when I was searching for "sandbox transactions not sending IPN" at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/:

> **How long is the IPN timeout length?**
>
> PayPal's Instant Payment Notification (IPN) system expects your web
>   server to send an HTTP 200 response when the IPN is sent to your IPN
>   script.
>
> If your server doesn't respond after a certain amount of time, the IPN
>   system then re-posts the IPN to your script.
>
> The amount of time between each re-post doubles each time: 10 seconds,
>   20 seconds, 40 seconds, 80 seconds, and so on, up to a maximum of 24
>   hours. The IPN system stops re-posting when:
>
> - PayPal receives a basic HTTP "200 OK" response from your web server, or
> - When approximately four days have passed since the initial post.

Note that if your IPN listener is spending more than 10 seconds getting to its end where it responds with the HTTP 200 result (as shown in the sample code), you are doing something *very* wrong:  An IPN handler should be a ***really quick*** process, executing as fast as possible, *especially* if you want to handle significant volumes of traffic.